# What kind of revolver did Tuco have?

Tags: better-call-saul

In the series *Better Call Saul*, in the second episode, where Tuco points a revolver at Saul, we can notice how unusually large the cylinder of the revolver looks.

What is its make? Is it a real model or some custom revolver made either by Tuco or the show's creators?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Internet Movie Firearms Database identifies it as a "[Taurus Raging Judge M513](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Better_Call_Saul#Taurus_Raging_Judge_M513)"

[image]

As far as I can tell, the model shown on the show is a stock model, albeit one that's relatively rare.